# How to amend contents of txt and save as a csv in new folder

Tags: csv, batch-file, converters

I am new to this and have tried searching the forums etc for an answer, and have got partially there but need help to get to the end.

What it is - I need a program - something basic i.e. a .bat file to take .txt files from folder A, amend the contents of the files (replace all commas with semicolons) and move them to folder B but as a .csv file not a text file.

At max there would be say 20 small files to be 'converted'

I've found the following code to replace all , with ; and to save as a .csv file

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims==" %%A in (13-06-477.txt) do set string=%%A & echo !string:  =;! >> 13-06-477.csv
```

but this converts a specified file and not a folder with multiple files a variable names. Can someone please help?

Many thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Sample script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "fldrin=Folder A"
set "fldrou=Folder B"
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /B "%fldrin%\*.txt"') do (
    echo in="%fldrin%\%%~G" out="%fldrou%\%%~nG.csv"
    rem type nul>"%fldrou%\%%~nG.csv"
    for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%fldrin%\%%~G") do (
        set "string=%%A"
        echo !string:,=;!
        rem echo !string:,=;!>>"%fldrou%\%%~nG.csv"
    )
)
```

There are some practices used in the sample script (see links to resources):

- `for` [loop commands](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- `~` [argument modifiers](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Check the output carefully. Then you could remove `rem` no sooner than debugged.

**Real script**

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "fldrin=D:\bat\files\29030979 in"
set "fldrou=D:\bat\files\29030979 ou"
md "%fldrou%" 2>nul
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /B "%fldrin%\*.txt"') do (
    echo in="%fldrin%\%%~G" out="%fldrou%\%%~nG.csv"
    type nul>"%fldrou%\%%~nG.csv"
    for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%fldrin%\%%~G") do (
        set "string=%%A"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo !string:,=;!
        echo !string:,=;!>>"%fldrou%\%%~nG.csv"
        endlocal
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

**Output**: should answer your additional questions about `.bat` and `.txt` file(s) placement and name(s) as well.

```
d:\bat>D:\bat\StackOverflow\29030979.bat
in="D:\bat\files\29030979 in\15-03-2015-A.txt" out="D:\bat\files\29030979 ou\15-03-2015-A.csv"
15-03-2015-A.txt; 16.03.2015; 15:04:28;31
15-03-2015-A.txt; 16.03.2015; 15:04:36;19
15-03-2015-A.txt; 16.03.2015; 15:05:23;66
in="D:\bat\files\29030979 in\15-03-2015-B.txt" out="D:\bat\files\29030979 ou\15-03-2015-B.csv"
15-03-2015-B.txt; 16.03.2015; 15:04:28;31
15-03-2015-B.txt; 16.03.2015; 15:04:36;19
15-03-2015-B.txt; 16.03.2015; 15:05:23;66

d:\bat>type "D:\bat\files\29030979 ou\15-03-2015-A.csv"
15-03-2015-A.txt; 16.03.2015; 15:04:28;31
15-03-2015-A.txt; 16.03.2015; 15:04:36;19
15-03-2015-A.txt; 16.03.2015; 15:05:23;66

d:\bat>
```

Input files obtained as a rerun result of

```
for /F "tokens=*" %G in ('dir /B /S "D:\bat\files\29030979 in"') do @echo %~nxG, %date%, %time%>>"%~fG"
```

Comment: Do i place the .bat in the same folder where to target folders are located? Do i just write the name of the folder or as a directory path? The files that are to be converted tend to follow -"15-03-201-A.txt" kind of format, will this influence outcome? Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, in the first answer version a `"` sign of quotation has dropped out, the line  should be  `for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /B "%fldrin%\*.txt"') do (`